# babel arabic changes enumeration level

Tags: numbering, koma-script, babel, arabic

I am trying to add a few short words of Arabic to my English document. This is working, by and large:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
It is called \AR{‏بحر لوط} (\emph{Bahr L\={u}t}), the Sea of Lot.

\end{document}
```

The only problem is that \section is rendered as "0.1 Introduction", when it should be "1 Introduction". When I change

```
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
```

to

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

i.e. remove arabic, enumeration works exactly as expected.

Is that a known side effect of the babel package? Can anybody confirm? More importantly, what to do about it? I suppose I could use `\chapter` instead of `\section`, but I'd rather not. I am open to alternative solutions however, all I need is a reliable way to add `‏بحر لوط` to my PDF (preferably without having to resort to LuaTeX or XeTeX).

Comment: I get an error in the `\section` line, don't you?

Comment: You are right. I am getting `Undefined control sequence. [\section{Introduction}]`. It still compiles, though.

Comment: Further experiments show this to be working with `\documentclass{article}`, probably making this an issue with KOMA-Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm this as an issue with KOMA-Script which will be brought to the attention of its author. For the time being I am simply using `\RL{b.hr lw.t}` from the `arabtex` package.